# How to make AutoFixture choose from a number of TypeRelays at random?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, autofixture

I have an abstract base class, say Base, and a number of derived classes, let's say D1, D2, D3.

How can I set up AutoFixture to choose one of D1, D2, D3, at random when a request for Base comes in?

Adding a TypeRelay for each of D1,D2,D3 to Fixture.Customizations seems to make it always pick the first one added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to throw together the following code.  If for some reason one of the requests fails, it will fall back to the specified default, so that one should be fail proof.  It doesn't use TypeRelay exactly, but the effect is essentially the same.

```
public class RandomCustomization<T> : ICustomization
{
    private readonly Type _defaultType;
    private readonly Type[] _types;
    public RandomCustomization(Type defaultType, params Type[] types)
    {
        _defaultType = defaultType;
        _types = types;
    }
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<T>(v => v.FromFactory(new RandomFactory(_defaultType, _types)));
    }
}

public class RandomFactory : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    private readonly Type _defaultType;
    private readonly Type[] _types;
    private readonly Random _ran = new Random();

    public RandomFactory(Type defaultType, params Type[] types)
    {
        _defaultType = defaultType;
        _types = defaultType.Concat(types).ToArray();
    }
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var which = _types[_ran.Next() % _types.Length];
        var toret = context.Resolve(which);
        if (toret == null || toret is OmitSpecimen)
        {
            toret = context.Resolve(_defaultType);
        }
        return toret;
    }
}
```